# Did suited Darth Vader have yellow eyes?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader

Anakin is seen only twice with yellow eyes in *Revenge of the Sith*, and I know it is a sign of fully embracing the dark side and hatred.  Given we never see Vader's face until the end of *Return of the Jedi*, in which he is redeemed and has normal eyes, I was wondering if there were any canon or Legends pieces of evidence towards Vader's yellow eyes.

Comment: Good question! I know there were several scenes where he was helmetless in EU/legends (Shadows of the Empire?), so this might have an answer. But I honestly don't ever recall his eyes being explicitly mentioned in those.

Comment: Darth Vader has yellow eyes?? Was Darth Vader inspired by Scut Farkas?

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Yes, he did in both continuities.

**Canon:**

In the *Star Wars: Rebels* episode *[Twilight of the Apprentice](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Twilight_of_the_Apprentice)*, Vader's helmet breaks and a yellow eye can be seen.

[image: Vader's eyes, canon]

**Legends:**

From *[Star Wars: Purge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Purge)*, a Legends comic:

[image: Vader's eyes, Legends 1]

From one of the Dark Horse Star Wars Legends comics:

[image: Vader's eyes, Legends 2 (Unidentified comic)]

He also seems to have yellow eyes in *[Star Wars: The Force Unleashed](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Unleashed)*, though they're less obvious:

[image: Vader's eyes, Legends 3]

Comment: If anyone can identify what comic that photo's from, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Um. Granting the fact that people who know me sometimes call me "color stupid" and thus I may very well be wrong, doesn't image #2 show RED, not yellow eyes? Awsome example on #1 though

Comment: @DVK A noticeable part of the eyes are yellow, so I believe it counts.

Comment: @roge - zooming in, he has yellow **SQUARE IRISES**, you're right! WTF? Either someone had issues with anatomy, or there is something weird going on.

Comment: @DVK I'm seeing another dress, mmm?

Comment: @DVK: to me it looks like red irises with square yellow pupils

Comment: @sumelic - ssorry, used wrong word. What you said

Comment: Yay for canon info!

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe there is any -canon- evidence to support him having yellow eyes. Not all individuals show outward signs of dark side corruption (Palpatine for example.) Given that Anakin did show signs of said corruption I believe it can safely be presumed that he had yellow eyes right up to the end of his life. It's also notable that many who returned to the LS or a neutral following of the force after obtaining dark side corruption characteristics never fully regained their normal appearance(EU.)

Comment: Dooku didn't have especially yellow eyes.

Comment: I was watching 1-6 with a friend of mine and there's nothing in the movie to definitively prove Dooku was evil. Given that he extends the offer to Obi-wan to help him in overthrowing Sideous it's entirely possible the offer was genuine and Dooku's actions were a ruse to undermine the Sith from within.

Comment: Dooku was bankrolling the separatists. At the very least his actions led (knowingly) to acts of genocide on thousands of world and, ultimately, to the creation of the Empire and the destruction of Alderaan.

Comment: Based on everything we've seen in canon and EU, dark side corruption is based on intent and state of mind. Dooku could have believed in the greater good.

Comment: @Minativ7 - so did Anakin and Vader, actually. Law and Order and all that idealist drivel. {{insert incendiary political commentary }}

Comment: It can also be argued that Anakin's DS corruption was a result of his selfishness(Padme) Sadism(Temple Jedi/Defenseless Sandpeople) and willful ignorance. He was willing to commit atrocity for the sake of his own banal obsession with Padme.

Comment: @Minativ7 - "sadism" doesn't mean what your comment implies you think it means. It means deriving pleasure (technically, of a sexual kind) from inflicting pain. What he did was cruelty and sociopathy, for sure, but he derived no **pleasure** from killing in the temple. Ditto with sandpeople - he merely satisfied his need for revenge, he didn't just kill them to get pleasure. I do agree that he basically went Dark over a romantic attachment he was afraid to lose. Good call.

Comment: I disagree, I believe he did enjoy it. There are plenty of examples in EU of his sadism, and that's why i use that word. If it was purely vengeful, why kill those who didn't wrong him in any way?

Comment: @Minativ7 - Disney canon definitely disagrees. He found killing distasteful in "The Sith Lords" book and even went as far as to stop the Emperor from killing a girl.

Comment: I just got the avoid extended discussion thing, but I will review Disney's canon.

Comment: @Minativ7 - if you find a specific example proving me wrong (that he derived pleasure from killing/pain), feel free to ping me on this thread and I'll post it as a question you can answer. Or you can ask and asnwer your own question as well if you prefer, it is permitted

Comment: This is answer isn't true. The canon show *Rebels* showed him with yellow eyes.